# How to tell a response is preflight and what to do with it?

Tags: cors

I have managed to get a response to my POST. It is clearly a response to a preflight request. Here is the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 24 Jan 2019 00:19:54 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.36
Set-Cookie: cisession=ok8ilu3sqp51i2s6tkkuoh6aa9r9oeu6; expires=Thu, 24-Jan-
2019 08:19:55 GMT; Max-Age=28800; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept,Authorization,Content-Type,Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

My browser code is getting the 200 and then choking because it expects the responseText to be a json buffer. But it is not. What it is getting back is an empty response to the preflight request in the "onload" event. I tried waiting for onloadend, but get the same empty responseText. So what do I do here? Just ignore the first status=200 and wait for the real one? The first 200 is from the preflight response and is useless to me. Is there some field in the preflight response that tells me it was just an informational transmission?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. "My browser code" — Are you writing your own web browser? And are currently having problems implementing XMLHttpRequest or fetch?

Comment: _“It is clearly a response to a preflight request”_ - explain how you figure that it was? You should never have to deal with a preflight request on the client side yourself - that is all stuff that gets handled internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a response to a POST request, then it won't be a response to a preflight request.

A preflight request is an OPTIONS request (and will be sent automatically by the browser, so isn't something you need to concern yourself with too much unless you are writing your own web browser or server-side code that needs to respond to it).

Note that if you make a request which requires a preflight, then the `Access-Control-*` headers need to be set in **both** the response to the preflight and the response to the actual request.

If you make a POST request and got this back, then you've just made a request to which the server has responded with a zero length (and thus invalid) HTML document.

Comment: I think you are right. Seems that my this->input->is_ajax_request() is failing. I will try to figure out why.